# CSS: How to limit horizontal/vertical scrolling?

Tags: html, css

## Details

I have made a `div` navigator for my website, there are 4 menu buttons which float left, and 1 authentication button which floats right. The navigators position is relative so it doesn't move.

CODE

```css
body {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 101.6%;
  height: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  /*background-image: url('images/logo.png');
 width: 150px;
 height: 155px;*/
  font-size: 32pt;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  width: 101%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 7%;
  max-width: 102.5%;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Button1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 15%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 3%;
  padding: 25px 2px 55px 2px;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button1:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.Button2 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 10%;
  left: 23%;
  top: 10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  width: 7%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px 55px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button2:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.Button3 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 10%;
  left: 23%;
  top: 3%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px 55px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button3:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.Button4 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 10%;
  left: 23%;
  top: 3%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px 55px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button4:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.Button5 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 10%;
  left: 23%;
  top: 3%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px 55px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button5:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.Button6 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 10%;
  left: 23%;
  top: 8%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 10%;
  width: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 28px 0px 55px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  ;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.Button6:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.signin {
  float: right;
  width: 114px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  color: red;
}
.mainpage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a class="logo" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">My Website</a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="Button1" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 1</a>
  <a class="Button2" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 2</a>
  <a class="Button3" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 3</a>
  <a class="Button4" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 4</a>
  <a class="Button5" href="/support" style="text-decoration:none">Button 5</a>
  <a class="Button5" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 6</a>
  <a class="signin" href="/login" style="text-decoration:none">AuthButton</a>
</div>

<div class="mainpage"></div>
<!-- This is page under the navigator for placing the content, right now it's empty -->
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3125ygjf/1).

---

## Problem

Unfortunately if you look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3125ygjf/1/embedded/result), and try to scroll horizontally you will see the overflow and it would just stay there, even though when I had the bottom content container `mainpage` div with the `height` of 100% and `width` of 80%, it would still be able to scroll down when there's nothing there at all.

As you see this code below, I have tried to limit `html` and `body` with specific resolution, which didn't fix my problem.

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%}
```

## Question

How could i limit my page from being scrolled in specific resolution only?

Can resolution be greater than value of 100% so it can work?

Comment: Just offhand... `.main { width: 101.6%;}` could quite possibly be the issue -- since it's *more* than 100%.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not, menu div is still greater than 100% and can still be scrolled, i just did it to make both of them equal with width, even if both values are 100% nothing would work, maybe it's margin? @Scott

Comment: That was just one example.. there are other areas in the CSS where you've clearly got things set to more than 100%.

Comment: can you show me the keys? i can't see any keys that have value width/height more than 100% except those 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is here:

```css
.main {
  width: 101.6%;
}
.mainpage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

I tweaked your code merging all those `buttons` classes into one. you had invalid/unused properties there.

you need to fix those properties mentioned above like this:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2B2B2B
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9)
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*background-image: url('images/logo.png');
 width: 150px;
 height: 155px;*/
  font-size: 32pt;
  color: white;
  margin: 3% 0 0 1%
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  border: solid rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%
}
.Button {
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px 2px 55px;
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-width: 0 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  width: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none
}
.Button:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.signin {
  float: right;
  width: 114px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  color: red;
}
.mainpage {
  height: calc(100% - 216px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a class="logo" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">My Website</a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="Button b1" href="/">Button 1</a>
  <a class="Button b2" href="/">Button 2</a>
  <a class="Button b3" href="/">Button 3</a>
  <a class="Button b4" href="/">Button 4</a>
  <a class="Button b5" href="/support">Button 5</a>
  <a class="Button b6" href="/">Button 6</a>
  <a class="signin" href="/login">AuthButton</a>
</div>

<div class="mainpage"></div>
<!-- This is page under the navigator for placing the content, right now it's empty -->
```

Comment: That would not help, as if both values are 100%, menu div is still greater than that in visual, maybe it's margin, that code would just make a change in color but the scrolling vertically would still be possible.

Comment: Thank's alot! worked fine! so problem was not having box-sizing and obviously exceeding width/height of 100%?

Comment: essentially yes, but you sill have a few things to improve in your code, I'm still gonna update the answer

Comment: @ShellRox When you set a width to 100% and use padding and/or border, the element grows with their size, `box-sizing: border-box` prevents that and make their size be included in the set width

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with smaller CSS can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/3125ygjf/3/

Perhaps you should also have a look at the flexbox-model. There you don't have to care about the absolute positioning. The container gets `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`and than you can place the header, menu and main in there. You just have give the main-div the needed hight and make it scrollable. That's it.

*edit: In addition all your buttons have a width of 7% i.e. This will cause trouble later on when you change the text for example. Try to avoid such width-values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong in your code, I will list as many as I could notice:

1. `div` elements by default are 100% width, so you do not need to specify it. If you are trying to make some sort of *hack* using more than 100% because it is not fitting the whole x-axis of your viewport, something is wrong with your code.
2. A class serves as a multiple selector, meaning that you can just use one class for all your buttons if they all share the same CSS properties.
3. If you are defining `max-height` and `min-height` with the same value, why not just use `height`.
4. `body` has a margin by default in different browsers, generally it is around 8px, so you can remove it by using `margin: 0`.
5. Your main css property should always come **after** your vendor prefixes such as `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc.
6. When you use zero in your css properties, there is no need to specify px, pt, % or any other unit, since 0 will always be computed as 0px.

---

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/u6kb2aej/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  margin: 0
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /*background-image: url('images/logo.png');
 width: 150px;
 height: 155px;*/
  font-size: 32pt;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 10pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px 0 55px 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 70px;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.signin {
  float: right;
  width: 114px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  color: red;
}
.mainpage {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a class="logo" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">My Website</a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="btn" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 2</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 3</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 4</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/support" style="text-decoration:none">Button 5</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Button 6</a>
  <a class="signin" href="/login" style="text-decoration:none">AuthButton</a>
</div>

<div class="mainpage"></div>
<!-- This is page under the navigator for placing the content, right now it's empty -->
```